# What is the difference between [ ] and [[ ]] in R?

Tags: r

```
  > levels(state.region)[2]
    [1] "S"
    > levels(state.region)[[2]]
    [1] "S"
```

They return the same value, so I don't know what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[] = always returns object of same class (out of basic object classes), can select more than one element of an object

[[]] = can extract one element from list or data frame, returned object (out of basic object classes) not necessarily list/dataframe

Comment: `[[` can extract from more that just a list or data.frame. It also works with vectors, matrices, environments, etc.

Comment: very late here... but what use is `[[` when applied to a vector or matrix?  I can't think of any examples where it differs from `[` (just like the OP's question demonstrates).