# Use dollar $ sign to access a column

Tags: r

This question may seem stupid, but I am curious about how to access a column by a column name with quote in data.frame, such as:

```r
col.name <- colnames(feature)[i]   # feature is a data frame, i is the index
feature$col.name   # but this returns NULL
```

Comment: Use extractor `[[`: `feature[[col.name]]`

Comment: this is definitely a FAQ, but it's hard to search for `$` (in fact I can't find the appropriate duplicate even after searching for a few minutes ...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33462844/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10875511/3358272. Google is better at it than Stack, [`site:stackoverflow.com "r" "$" "[["`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"r"+"%24"+"[[").

Comment: @r2evans these are mostly about "difference between [ and [[", not "how do index indirectly with $" (@user20650's suggestion works). I think I'm going to tag that one with [r-faq] so I can find it again ...

Comment: Yeah, @BenBolker, thank you for checking me on that (one reason I didn't close the question quickly): I'm too distracted at the moment to do an earnest look at all of them, those looked somewhat promising.

Comment: Thanks! I searched but failed to find the answer as dollar sign is not accounted for using Google